# Running selenium webdriver in amazon lambda python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

I want to run BeautifulSoup and selenium webdriver in amazon lambda and my running environment is python 3.6. Is it possible to run ? if so How. My intention is to scrap datas from a webpage using beautiful soup 4 and selenium(Since it has to scrap data dynamically generated by javascript).

Comment: What is the error you face when you try it?

Comment: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'bs4', and Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named ' "Selenium"' @TarunLalwani

Comment: Did you package those modules as instructed by lambda? Also do remember that there will be no `firefox` or `chrome` inside your lambda. So you need to have a external grid which needs to be available to your `lambda` for it to work

Comment: you can scrap without using selenium also. if you need to click some button or scroll then check for the xhr request in network tab

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to package a headless Chrome binary and chromedriver along with all the Python packages you need. You'll also need to set several options in Selenium's Chrome web driver to make it work.

I wrote a [step-by-step tutorial](http://robertorocha.info/setting-up-a-selenium-web-scraper-on-aws-lambda-with-python/) after spending several frustrating weeks trying to deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) and upload it to Lambda if you are going to use dependancies outside of the standard library.

I have a [write up](https://medium.com/@nZenitram/medium-lambda-and-me-or-how-i-export-medium-stories-to-my-website-148b599ad271) about using BS4 and Lambda together. I did not use Selenium within Lambda but I do have extensive Selenium experience. You will not be able to execute commands within a browser using Lambda. You are going to need to have a remote server stood up, running [Selenium Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). Download Selenium and the webdrivers on the machine that you wish to do the web scraping, start the `.jar` file, it will open a port on the machine Selenium will communicate with.

Considering that you will need a machine running probably windows to fire up a browser and scrape these pages, you probably don't need lambda in the end.

Comment: You can definitely use selenium inside Lambda using this as a starting point: https://github.com/21Buttons/pychromeless

Comment: You can run any application headless pretty much.. as long as there is a way to control it without a mouse