# AWS lambda layer with chromedriver and headless chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, lambda

I have a java lambda function that uses selenium to run a screen scraper to pull back some data.
The function is ready to go, but I cannot figure out how to access the chromedriver and headless chrome ( as they are 3rd party executables).

Is there a lambda-layer that I can use that already has these resources in place?

OR

How do I upload these resources with my lambda?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running selenium webdriver in amazon lambda python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953271/running-selenium-webdriver-in-amazon-lambda-python)